# Failed to decode response content using IdHttp

Tags: delphi, encoding, indy, idhttp

I use TIdHttp to fetch web content. The response header indicates the content encoding to be utf8. I want to print content in console as CP936 (simplified chinese), but the actual content is not readable.

```
Result := TEncoding.Utf8.GetString(ResponseBuffer);
```

I do the same thing in python (using httplib2) without any problems.

```
def python_try():
    conn = httplib2.HttpConn()
    respose, content = conn.get(...)
    print content.decode('utf8') # readable in console
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

I debugged the raw response and noticed that the content is gzipped.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2012 15:27:44 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I tried to assign a IdCompressorZLib instance to IdHttp instance. Unfortunately, the application will crash while decompressing gzipped content. The test address is "http\://www.baidu.com" (encoding=gb2312).

---

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried to download a gzipped jquery script file, which contains only ascii chars. This time it works, which means to be a problem of Indy library. If I were not wrong, I should close the question.

Comment: Buffers don't "detect" things; they just hold data. What's really doing the detecting? What code page or encoding did you *expect* to receive? Are either UTF-8 or 936 correct?

Comment: When you say failed, what do you mean? The first variant should be what you need, but it converts to UTF-16LE, and not straight to your code page. The last variant is getting there, but does a conversion to many? I would guess you'd simply need `Cp936Encoding.GetString(TEncoding.Utf8.GetString(ResponseBuffer));`

Comment: The python code shows that variant 1 is correct one, if it displays incorrectly with variant 1, then that's just a problem with *display* , not the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` handles the gzip decompression for you, if you have a `TIdCompressorZLib` component assigned to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property. Otherwise, you will have to decompress it manually (`TIdHTTP` will not send an `Accept-Encoding` header by default if the `Compressor` property is not assigned).

As for the UTF-8 encoding, `TIdHTTP` also handles that for you as well, if you are calling the overloaded version of the `TIdHTTP.Get()` or `TIdHTTP.Post()` method that returns a `String` value instead of fill a `TStream` object.  It will decode the UTF-8 to UTF-16 for you.  To convert that to CP936, you can let the RTL do the conversion for you:

```
type
  Cp936String = type AnsiString(936);
var
  S: Cp936String;
begin
  S := Cp936String(IdHTTP1.Get(...));
```

Comment: When I set a compressor, downloading process will crash. An access violation will occur during contents to be decoded.

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using? What is the full error message?

Comment: 'access violation at 0x00000038: read of address 0x00000038'. at IdZLib.pas(368): "if LocalTryStreamType(Result) then begin". The indy I am using is from delphi xe2.

Comment: I have not run into that AV before. Can you provide the actual URL you are downloading from?

Comment: You can simply try IdHttp1.Get('http\://www.baidu.com') with IdCompressorZLib1 to reproceduce the crash.

Comment: After fixing your malformed URL, `TIdHTTP.Get('http://www.baidu.com')` fails with an `EIdConnClosedGracefully` exception, with or without a `TIdCompressorZLib` assigned to it, if I use the default `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property value. The webserver closes the connection without sending any response back. If I then change the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property value to match the IE9 webbrowser, everything works fine. I get a compressed response that decompresses and decodes properly with the current Indy 10 release.

Comment: The indy I am using, is shipped with xe2. I do the same as you have done, but always get a crash. Do you mean I have to deinstall indy and to rebuild the current indy library? It would be great, if I only have to overwrite several source files.

Comment: If you have Runtime Packages disabled, you can try downloading the latest `IdCompressorZLib.pas` file and add it to your project. I don't recall offhand any interface changes made to that unit lately. You might not be so lucky with `IdHTTP.pas`, though. Recompiling the entire library is best, but do [read the install notes](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) first.

Comment: I see this is marked as answered, but it is kind of vague as to what the solution was.  I got the entire Indy package and installed it in XE2 and it still crashes.

Comment: @DarinBallweg: It works fine for me in XE2 using the latest Indy version.  What is the exact crash you are seeing?

Comment: I missed deleting a few .dcu's from the Delphi win32 folder.  To make sure it is clean, I simply copied all my compiled .dcu's into the Delphi out put folder and then deleted them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any auto detect encoding, it cannot be done reliably.  Simply believe the Content-Type header.

```
Result := TEncoding.Utf8.GetString(ResponseBuffer);
```

If the Content-Type header is missing or lying, then you need to detect encoding. Although I would not use any algorithm that would misdetect UTF-8 as CP936...

Comment: As the python code works, I am not sure whether TIdHttp returns wrong content or it is just something wrong with encoding conversion.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 it has to do with the way you display the output... just save it to a file or something