# Binary HTTP response content when expecting JSON text

Tags: delphi, http, encoding, gzip, indy

I'm using delphi XE3 to Upload some Images to a server , i've intercepted the request with chrome and im basically sending the exact same request with IDhttp, server responds with a 200 OK so I guess everything went fine.
Problem is, I need to get the response content to get the links of the uploaded images, but all I get is :

```
    ‹      •ÒK
Ã  Ð»Ì:Ôù¨Õ\¥)P‚‹¤…,Cî^K–ÅÂlddà1¿ê:/e‡ñq@®kÙöúÚRÍ0Wº}&³–\çÉ×^   6   ä“‹ÄŽ's÷!²½½·Îá‡£¨â„1Ù€=I¥±Å$®¯±®¶ˆ‰±¯©íW¦Ûà?ËêFÖbñ=Ë©,j·Á¡gyÅßá_Öóü gÊr Á
```

What is this ? How can I get the Json Response ?

Response headers intercepted on Chrome are :

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:169
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 21 Nov 2013 12:29:40 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
p3p:CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Pragma:no-cache

    Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
    Vary:User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u3t-Type:application/json
```

Comment: remember those two `‹` and a "round" characters in the beginning - they are typical for GZip compression so they hints you to prove it by trying to GUnZip it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to decode response content using IdHttp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017186/failed-to-decode-response-content-using-idhttp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From response header:

```
 Content-Encoding:gzip
```

So it's compressed data. Don't allow compression in HTTP request or decompress the data using gzip.

Comment: or just do not disable Indy component to do decompress: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017186

Answer (score 3):

The response header indicates that the content is compressed:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

Be careful what you ask for. If you tell the server that you can accept gzip, the server may actually send it to you gzipped. You're probably manually setting the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Instead of sending a request header like the following:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

You can send a request header that says you don't want any encoding:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

See the following question for properly configuring `TIdHTTP` for gzip:

[Failed to decode response content using IdHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017186)