# Indy10 compression in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

I found a link that is marked as answered but the solution is not clear. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017186/failed-to-decode-response-content-using-idhttp)!

Indy10 is crashing in XE2 when trying to set compression to a servlet call. I have downloaded the entire Indy10 project and followed all the instructions for uninstalling and installing it. It always crashes when decompressing.

```
uses
IdHttp, IdCompressorZLib;

function CreateIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  IdHTTP.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(IdHTTP);
  Result := IdHTTP;
end;
```

Here is the call stack:

```
exception class   : EAccessViolation
exception message : Access violation at address 00000038. Write of address 00000038.

main thread ($368c):
00000038 +000 ???
17f56136 +00a census.DLL   IdZLibHeaders                inflateInitEx
17f5e8ab +00f census.DLL   IdZLib                       LocalTryStreamType
17f5e983 +037 census.DLL   IdZLib                       CheckInitInflateStream
17f5eb01 +0d5 census.DLL   IdZLib                       DecompressStream
17f5fbb4 +004 census.DLL   IdCompressorZLib             TIdCompressorZLib.InflateStream
17f28e84 +0a8 census.DLL   IdZLibCompressorBase         TIdZLibCompressorBase.DecompressGZipStream
17f53105 +379 census.DLL   IdHTTP                       TIdCustomHTTP.ReadResult
17f55a9b +2ef census.DLL   IdHTTP                       TIdHTTPProtocol.ProcessResponse
17f55f64 +1c0 census.DLL   IdHTTP                       TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest
17f55d5d +055 census.DLL   IdHTTP                       TIdCustomHTTP.Get
17f519e4 +030 census.DLL   IdHTTP                       TIdCustomHTTP.Get
182c577f +093 census.DLL   SEMess               390  +6 TECSMessaging.GetICFormDataFromServlet
182c541f +043 census.DLL   SEMess               296  +3 TECSMessaging.Timer1Timer
503e7397 +00f vcl160.bpl   Vcl                          Extctrls.TTimer.Timer
503e727b +02b vcl160.bpl   Vcl                          Extctrls.TTimer.WndProc
75bd7895 +00a USER32.dll                                DispatchMessageW
504525e7 +0f3 vcl160.bpl   Vcl                          Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage
5045262a +00a vcl160.bpl   Vcl                          Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage
5045295d +0c9 vcl160.bpl   Vcl                          Forms.TApplication.Run
```

Comment: Works fine for me in XE2 using the latest Indy version.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have not provided any details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for making me triple check what I did. I missed deleting a few .dcu's from the Delphi win32 folder.  To make sure it is clean, I simply copied all my compiled .dcu's into the Delphi out put folder and then deleted them.